# Difference between message-oriented and RPC oriented web services

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

[JAX-WS allows developers to write message-oriented as well as Remote Procedure Call-oriented (RPC-oriented) web services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html)

I am new to JAX-WS. I want to know what is the difference between message-oriented and remote procedure call-oriented web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RPC based the methods in a Web service are called through a RPC, i.e. in a synchronous way through a specific port and protocol.

But message-oriented is Message based Web Services the methods are called through an HTTP request using SOAP.

Read this excellent [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/).

Comment: IMHO, in both RPC and Message oriented WS, methods can called through HTTP. These models are not about programming model rather  It merely dictates how to translate a WSDL binding to a SOAP message. This is what the link suggests. I might be missing something. Please clarify a bit more.

Comment: from https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html: Message-oriented systems typically export relatively simple operation signatures and push the business intelligence into the messages they exchange. In a message-oriented system, received messages drive endpoint behaviour according to semantics encoded in the message header or payload. RPC-like services, on the other hand, encode more of their business semantics in their operation signatures.